# attr() not working but target will call other commands?

Tags: jquery, text, target, attr

Okay so this guy should be calling the number form the rel attribute in the target  tag, but it's returning as undefined:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first().attr('rel')
```

What's weird is that this will call the text in that  tag:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first().text()
```

...but when I used attr('rel') it's undefined??  How could this be?  An example  tag it's calling the text() from properly is:

```
<td colspan="6" class="country" rel="3">United States</td>
```

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to?

Comment: tr != td, you need to navigate to the element with the rel.

Comment: Is `rel` valid for tds?

Comment: Can you post the whole table you have... it might be easier to help you find the appropriate selection.

Comment: Jai - I have another working code in another place that calls a <td> with a rel, so I assume so
.

Comment: @Jai - No, according to the specs, `rel` is not a valid attribute for a `<tr>`: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

Comment: This might be the answer.  But what about a <td>?  My rel is in a <td> tag, and I'm also calling a rel attribute on a <td> somewhere else on the page and that sucker's working great.

Comment: The `rel` is not a valid attribute, but it will still work in most (all) browsers.  That's not the issue to your problem.  The issue is that you are not selecting the `<td>`, but its parent `<tr>`, which doesn't have a `rel`.  See my answer below for details.  See especially the last line where I explain why you think `text()` works, but in reality, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first()
```

With this code, you are not accessing the `<td>`, but the `<tr>`, so you can't access the `rel` attribute of it.

Let's split it apart:

```
$(this).closest('tr')
```

Whatever `$(this)` is, you are finding its closest parent `<tr>`

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)')
```

You are getting all the previous siblings to that `<tr>` that have a `<td>` with class `country`.

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first()
```

You select the first `<tr>` of the previous list of `<tr>`s

To get the `<td>`, you need to do something like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first().find('td')
```

EDIT:  As @KevinB points out below, the only reason `text()` makes you think it works is because `text()` returns the text of the element and all its children.  So you still get the `<tr>` back, but since that element doesn't have any text itself, you only see the text of its child `<td>`.

For proof that you are selecting the `<tr>` and NOT the `<td>`, do the following:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.country)').first().prop('tagName'));
```

This will output "TR" and not "TD".

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Notice the ":has(td.country)" part of the prevAll() call.  I am calling the <td> and the proof is that when I change "attr('rel')" to "text()" it properly calls the text in the <td>.

Comment: No, you are finding all previous `<tr>`s that have a `<td>` with class `country`.  It doesn't mean you get these `<td>`s back

Comment: @user1988799 .text() gets the text of the current element *and all children*, .text() isn't a good test. :has does not select children, it just filters the current set to elements that have an element that match the selector.

Comment: Ahhh, right; I'm getting text() from everything inside.  Thank you Steve & Kevin B.